# Database property not set in EntityConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

I am attempting to create a new connection with the following code:

```
using (EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection("name=SampleEntities")) 
{
    conn.Open();
}
```

I get the following error:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

It appears this is not working because the Database property of the `EntityConnection` class is not being set, but the Initial Catalog is set in the named connection in the app.config.

The connection string is the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="SampleEntities" 
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=PROGRAMMINGEFDB1;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This matches what is in the `EntityConnection.StoredConnection` property. This string will set the source correctly in the `EntityConnection` but not the database.

Comment: `Initial Catalog=` is a synonym for `database=` .....

Answer (score 0):

I created a new project to see if that would help.  When I went to create a new ADO Data Model, I realized I could not make a connection to the database, which is why the connection was not working.  It turns out SQL Server service refused to start.  I managed to fix this problem with this answer: [SQL Server 2012 can't start because of a login failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390921/sql-server-2012-cant-start-because-of-a-login-failure)